# the notification throw firebase work but without sound

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am using the cloud function (firebase) to send notifications which works fine but without sound, I do not know why..
any idea?

```
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
```

I tried this code but I still get the notification without sound

Comment: In Android or iOS?

Comment: @AbhiTripathi on iOS

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
sound: default,
```

in data or notification. Like this

```
{

data: {
    
    ..........        
  },
  notification: {
         sound: default,
       }
}
```

In your JSON request.

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: In your JSON that you're sending to your firebase server. If you're testing with firebase console it won't work. Use postman to manually send notification if you dont have a server now.